# Changing ordering of authorship in a proceeding

Tags: journals, conference, authorship

In the field of applied math where a paper has been accepted for a conference presentation (talk), is it common for the ordering of the authors to be changed for a proceeding that entails thereafter?

Comment: Changed by who? Math typically uses alphabetical ordering of names.

Comment: Presumably, the OP means _for the corresponding conference paper that will appear in the proceedings_?

Comment: Also, do you want to know whether it is common (as you have asked), generally acceptable, or possible? For _common_, I suspect answers will be subjective, because I doubt datasets exist. For _generally acceptable_, it is still somewhat subjective. I'd argue _yes_, it is generally acceptable (in some fields), because many conferences don't define rules on changing the author order (whereas journals more typically do). For _possible_, the answer is _yes_. If the rules don't forbid it, then just do it, otherwise, ask permission.

Comment: @Buffy: Not in applied math.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth, thanks.I learn something new every day.

Comment: Why do you want to change it?

Comment: In my experience (materials science), it is not uncommon that between the abstract submission (months before the conference) and the submission of the conference proceedings (at or after the conference) that the scope of the talk and paper may well change. This may result in adding new authors or shuffling the order of authors. It can be a moving target.

Comment: @lordy because the workload and principal academic contributions by the authors is no longer in tandem with the ordering of their authorship. My question is whether is ground for a negotiation.

Comment: Does it matter that much? In my field, unless you're changing the first author, your position on the author list at a conference matters very little.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quite frequently occurring extreme case which may help you evaluate your own situation:

As @JonCuster also mentioned in their comment, there is always plenty of time between the abstract submission and the presentation itself, and the work typically evolves a lot during that period. Imagine it evolved such that new collaborators were added. Adding new names in there may change the list of authorship a lot. Imagine also that you actually submitted the manuscript by the time you present it, of course with the co-authors on it. In the conference, strictly adhering to the list of authors submitted in the abstract would mean removing your new co-authors, which should be out of question as it is best practice to give them credit as co-authors of your work. Thus, the list of authors can definitely change during the actual presentation as one is usually entitled to also present improvements to one's work. Whether it is common in your field, I don't know, but my guess would be that it is not too rare.

Answer (score 1):

My experience is it is no big deal provided the papers are not set for publishing. I would consider it similar to any other minor edit to the paper. If it can be done logistically fine.  If it requires review, and authors wouldn't, not fine.

Answer (score 0):

In general it is **not** possible to change the order of authorship once a piece of work is accepted at a conference/journal etc. This is for several reasons:

1. Authors should think about the order of the authors before they
   submit and if the work contributions afterwards change then this
   work is normally not part of the submission and what counts is what
   was submitted on not if further work was put into it later.
2. The reluctance to change authorships also comes from the fact that
   sometimes authors try to get their name of a fraudulent paper and
   this is something journals want to avoid at all.

If you can prove **exceptional circumstances** and all other authors agree (in writting) you might have a change by writing to who ever is in charge. But this should only be done if really necessary and you have a really good reason.

Comment: Is having two first authors an alternative to havin one first author?

Comment: Yes, you can put "shared" but be aware that it then will most of the time count just half as well.